# Method Chaining when no object was constructed

Tags: c#, fluent-interface

In my current Net Framework 4 project, I did this:

- defined my class constructor as private
- called static class method to obtain object of that class
- invoked methods of that freshly constructed object, which could fail

This looks in a following manner:

```
MyClassName obj = MyClassName.GetObject("Name").DoJob().Close();
```

where

- GetObject is a static method that returns instance of MyClassName OR NULL (I specifically want to return null on creation failure, since no other way came to mind)
- DoJob() and Close() are instance methods, they return `this` and will throw a `System.NullReferenceException` when GetObject fails, or anything inbetween fails.

**Problem is**: Is it possible to design this in the way I want, without try-catch blocks? I want to have many, many one liners versus `try - lineOfCode - catch`. Every line will be another object doing its specific task and destroying itself / being forgotten. I don't really need to use `MyClassName obj =` part either.

Comment: That's where C#6's null-conditional operator `?.` must shine! http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx

Comment: Uhhhh, I should mention I'm working with Net Framework 4 for this project...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of returning `null` value, you could return a null object as part of [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

In this case, this object would do nothing when `DoJob` and `Close` is called and just return itself.

The possible problem might be need to define some kind of simple class hierarchy to implement this pattern. Which might seem like overkill when you have just one class right now.

Comment: ... or if one is too bored of imperative OO paradigm - they might implement a [Maybe Monad](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.co.nz/2011/01/monads-in-c-5-maybe.html) instead PS: the link is random, but the article looks legit PPS: this also looks promising: https://github.com/louthy/csharp-monad

Comment: @zerkms The problem with Maybe's in C# is lack of language support. Stuff like Option types only makes sense when you have language support, because otherwise, you have tons of boilerplate code.

Comment: For me it looks more than acceptable though: `var result = MaybeGetAnInt().Match(
                        Just: v => v * 10,
                        Nothing: 0
                     );` It's concise and readable

Comment: Well, after practicing some, I just made NullClassName that derives from MyClassName and virtualised key methods. When creation failed I would create and return NullObject, which then does nothing at all. Problem is I need to define NullClassName1, NullClassName2, NullClassName3 for remaining MyClassName1, MyClassName2 and so on... Well, that's OK, as long as I won't have to worry about exceptions. Thanks for pointing me in somewhat right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

Second option suggested by zerkms is to use some kind of `Option` type instead of nullable value.

So, using [Option library](https://github.com/tejacques/Option) for C#. Your code could look something like:

```
// simplified skeleton
class MyClassName
{
    private MyClassName() {}

    public MyClassName GetObject(string name)
    {
        return new MyClassName();
    }

    public MyClassName DoJob() { return this; }
    public MyClassName Close() { return this; }
}

Option<MyClassName> obj = MyClassName.GetObject("Name").ToOption().Select(x=>x.DoJob()).Select(x=>x.Close());

if (obj.HasValue)
{
    // can work with obj.Value
}
else
{
    // somewhere was null
}
```

Yeah, I agree there is some noise, but those are limits of the language.